# Linear approximation of $ e^x near x-0 $

Tags: calculus

So I've stuck this into the formula.
$$(e^x)+e^x(x-0)$$
$$(1)+1(x-0)$$

1+x

Is this the answer?

Comment: Yes, and we can also say that $y = 1 + x$ is the *tangent line approximation* to $e^x$ at $x = 0$.

Comment: Yes, linear approximation is the first derivative plus its value.

Comment: Yes, $1+x$ is the answer. Your argument may be incorrect, you should not have $(e^x)+e^x(x-0)$ in it.

Comment: @aero26 : $\:$ Do you mean "$\hspace{-0.02 in}e^x$ near $x\hspace{-0.04 in}=\hspace{-0.04 in}0$"? $\;\;\;\;$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the mean value theorem:

$\frac{e^x - e^0}{x - 0} = e^{h}$, $h \in [0,x]$. This can be rewritten as $e^x = 1 + e^h x$.

Now you can say that since $x$ is supposed to be small, $e^h$ is reasonably close to $1$ (as you take x smaller you are pushing $h$ closer to $0$). Of course there are ways of estimating the error :)